# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' in Microsoft dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am new to Microsoft dynamics, every time I am running performance test on the recorded script I am getting the following error:

```
Generate_Collection_Request_Performance Scenario1   <none>  Test Error  TestError   Test method MS.Dynamics.Performance.Application.TaskRecorder.Generate_Collection_RequestPerf.Generate_Collection_Request_Performance threw exception: 
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden".
```

I tried the following code

```
<AuthenticatorConfiguration Id="SelfMintingAdminUser" Class="MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.SelfMintedTokenAuthenticator"> <!-- NOTE: admin username needs to be specified --> <Credentials Username="xxxx@xxx.com" /> </AuthenticatorConfiguration>
```

in CloudEnvironment.config, but error did not resolved. Can you please tell me how to give authorization?

Does anyone know how to resolve or what causes the error?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But I would guess: you are not authorized as you should be.

Comment: Dont put more information into comments: please update your question instead.